# R Shiny app disconnected from server issue on shinyio

Tags: r, shiny

So I tried deploying a `Shiny` which runs fine in `RStudio`. However, during the first deployment I got this error which I have never seen before.

```
Preparing to deploy application...DONE Uploading bundle for application: 1969928...Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : Timeout was reached: [api.shinyapps.io] Operation timed out after 10000 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received Calls: ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> Timing stopped at: 0 0 10
```

Then I deleted the app from `shinyio` and published the app again, which now according to `RStudio` successfully deploys, but the app fails to load as seen in the screenshot below:

[image]

[image]

I tried restarting `RStudio` but it did not fix the issue. How can I resolve this problem?

Code + data:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
library(janitor)

# Define UI for application 
ui =    fluidPage(
  navbarPage("HISPANIC AND TOTAL POPULATION BY GENDER AND AGE GROUP", theme = shinytheme("paper"),
             tabPanel("Pyramid Plots",
                      icon = icon("chart-area"),
                      plotlyOutput(outputId = "PP1",
                                   width = "1024px",
                                   height = "768px",
                                   inline = T),
                      plotlyOutput(outputId = "PP2",
                                   width = "1024px",
                                   height = "768px",
                                   inline = T),
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic 
server = function(input, output) {

pop_hisp_df = structure(list(age_group = c("<  5 years", "5 - 14", "15  -  24", 
"25  -  34", "35  -  44", "45  -  54", "55  -  64", "65  -  74", 
"75  -  84", "85 +", "<  5 years", "5 - 14", "15  -  24", "25  -  34", 
"35  -  44", "45  -  54", "55  -  64", "65  -  74", "75  -  84", 
"85 +"), Type = c("Males", "Males", "Males", "Males", "Males", 
"Males", "Males", "Males", "Males", "Males", "Females", "Females", 
"Females", "Females", "Females", "Females", "Females", "Females", 
"Females", "Females"), Value = c(-6, -13, -13, -15, -17, -15, 
-11, -6, -3, -1, 6, 12, 12, 14, 16, 15, 12, 7, 4, 2)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

pop_gen_df = structure(list(age_group = c("<  5 years", "5 - 14", "15  -  24", 
"25  -  34", "35  -  44", "45  -  54", "55  -  64", "65  -  74", 
"75  -  84", "85 +", "<  5 years", "5 - 14", "15  -  24", "25  -  34", 
"35  -  44", "45  -  54", "55  -  64", "65  -  74", "75  -  84", 
"85 +"), Type = c("Males", "Males", "Males", "Males", "Males", 
"Males", "Males", "Males", "Males", "Males", "Females", "Females", 
"Females", "Females", "Females", "Females", "Females", "Females", 
"Females", "Females"), Value = c(-6, -12, -12, -14, -13, -14, 
-13, -9, -4, -2, 6, 11, 11, 13, 13, 14, 13, 10, 5, 3)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")) 
  
  output$PP1 = renderPlotly({ 
    
    # Plot
    gg_pop_hisp = ggplot(pop_hisp_df, aes( x = forcats::as_factor(age_group), y = Value, fill = Type)) +
      geom_bar(data = subset(pop_hisp_df, Type == "Females"), stat = "identity") + 
      geom_bar(data = subset(pop_hisp_df, Type == "Males"), stat = "identity") +
      scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-20,20),
                         breaks=c(-15,-10,0,10,15),
                         labels=paste0(c(15,10,0,10,15),"%")) +          # CHANGE
      scale_fill_manual(name = "", values = c("Females"="#FC921F", "Males"="#149ECE"), labels = c("Females", "Males")) +
      ggtitle("HISPANIC POPULATION BY GENDER AND AGE GROUP") +
      labs(x = "AGE GROUPSP", y = "PERCENTAGE POPULATION", fill = "Gender") +
      theme_minimal() +
      theme(legend.position="bottom") +
      coord_flip()  
    
    # Interactive
    ggplotly(gg_pop_hisp) %>% 
      layout(
        legend = list(
          orientation = 'h', x = 0.3, y = -0.3, 
          title = list(text = '')
        )
      )
    
    })
  
  output$PP2 = renderPlotly({ 
    
    # Plot
    gg_pop_gen = ggplot(pop_gen_df, aes(x = forcats::as_factor(age_group), y = Value, fill = Type))  +
      geom_bar(data = subset(pop_gen_df, Type == "Females"), stat = "identity") + 
      geom_bar(data = subset(pop_gen_df, Type == "Males"), stat = "identity") + 
      #scale_y_continuous(labels = function(z) paste0(abs(z), "%")) +          # CHANGE
      scale_y_continuous(
        limits=c(-20,20),
        breaks=c(-15,-10,0,10,15),
        labels=paste0(c(15,10,0,10,15),"%")
      ) + 
      scale_fill_manual(name = "", values = c("Females"="#ED5151", "Males"="#6B6BD6"), labels = c("Females", "Males")) +
      ggtitle("TOTAL POPULATION BY AGE AND GENDER") +
      labs(x = "AGE GROUPS", y = "PERCENTAGE POPULATION", fill = "Gender") +
      theme_minimal() +
      theme(legend.position="bottom") +
      coord_flip()
    
    # Interactive
    ggplotly(gg_pop_gen) %>% 
      layout(
        legend = list(
          orientation = 'h', x = 0.3, y = -0.3, 
          title = list(text = '')
        )
      )
    
  })
}
# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: If you are using `shinyapps.io`, go to the settings for that app and increase the timeouts to their limits.

Comment: @Kitswas which setting exactly? under `General` the idle timeout is already 15 minutes.

Comment: If it fails immediately upon load, it can be a package dependency issue. Although you don't have any exotic packages there...

Comment: @DanAdams yes it fails immediately after load.

Comment: @Ed_Gravy Check the logs.

Comment: @Kitswas, yep the log pointed out that there was an `object` in the code not found, so after removing that the app has been successfully deployed, cheers. Sometimes little dickens like these breaks the whole app lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After deleting the app from the Shiny.io server, delete the old "reconnect" directory and contents from the app's directory in your local computer (reconnect automatically creates that file when you run the app for first time). This allows rsconnect to create a new .cdf file automatically.

The structure of that directory should be something like ".../ my_app_directory / reconnect / shinyapps.io / shiny_user_name / app_name.dcf"